# Impossible to log in after changing $PATH

Tags: boot, login, login-screen, paths

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. While updating TeXLive I changed the PATH in an obviously wrong way. Now I can't log in: when I enter the correct password it comes back to the log in page.

I connected on `tty1` using CTRL+Alt+F1. I got the error message

```
compaudit:105: command not found: getent
```

The error probably comes from PATH as

```
echo $PATH
```

returns only the path to texlive. The problem is I cannot edit any file since no commands are recognized (`vim`,`nano`, etc.)!

How can I overcome this? Any help appreciated as I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to solve my problem, this is how. I did not have a LiveUSB Linux so I rebooted with my Windows partition. I then installed [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) on Windows and was able to read my partition with Ubuntu. I corrected the erroneous `$PATH$` (I had made an mistake in the file `\etc\environment`) and rebooted.

Note that modifying a linux system file from windows is not recommended (I had got a "hard drive error" on the first Ubuntu boot after the modification from linux). I would rather recommend using a USB stick with a live version of Ubuntu.

I am still interested in any other solution, if any.

Answer (score 1):

You could have still startd the programs with their full path, for example `/usr/bin/vim`. Since most programs didn't work for you, you could have checked packages.ubuntu.com for their paths: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/nano/filelist

Alternatively you could have booted into recovery mode and opened a shell there I guess.

Comment: The recovery mode did not work as I had to log in. Indeed for the full path!